# More than 9 backreferences in gsub()

Tags: regex, r, gsub

How to use gsub with more than 9 backreferences? 
I would expect the output in the example below to be "e, g, i, j, o".

```
> test <- "abcdefghijklmnop"
> gsub("(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)", "\\5, \\7, \\9, \\10, \\15", test, perl = TRUE)
[1] "e, g, i, a0, a5"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [Regular Expressions with The R Language](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html):

> You can use the backreferences `\1` through `\9` in the replacement text to reinsert text matched by a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). There is no replacement text token for the overall match. Place the entire regex in a capturing group and then use `\1`.

But with PCRE you should be able to use [named groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html). So try `(?P<`*`name`*`>`*`regex`*`)` for groupd naming and `(?P=`*`name`*`)` as backreference.

Answer (score 4):

Use `strsplit` instead:

```
test <- "abcdefghijklmnop"
strsplit(test, "")[[1]][c(5, 7, 9, 10, 15)]
```

Answer (score 3):

It was my understanding that \10 would we understood as backreference 0 followed by a digit of 1. I think 9 is the max.

Answer (score 2):

The `stri_replace_*_regex` functions from the [stringi](http://stringi.rexamine.com) package do not have such limitations:

```
library("stringi")
stri_replace_all_regex("abcdefghijkl", "(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)", "$10$1$11$12")
## [1] "jakl"
```

If you want to follow the 1st capture group with 1, use e.g.

```
stri_replace_all_regex("abcdefghijkl", "(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)", "$10$1$1\\1$12")
## [1] "jaa1l"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplace.html), back references \10 to \99 works on some languages, but not most.

Those that are reported to work are

- [JGSoft](http://www.regular-expressions.info/jgsoft.html)
- [Python](http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html)
- [PHP preg](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html#preg)
- [REAL basic](http://www.regular-expressions.info/realbasic.html)

Answer (score 0):

This limitation to 9 backreferences is specific to the `sub()` and `gsub()`functions, not to functions like `grep()` and the like. Support for more than 9 backreferences in R implies using PCRE regular expression (i.e. the `perl=TRUE` argument);  however, even with this option, the sub() and gsub() functions do not support it.

The R documentation is explicit on this point:  see  `?regexp`

```
There can be more than 9 backreferences (but the replacement in sub can
only refer to the first 9).
```

Furthermore the idea of using named capture groups to circumvent this limitation is bound to fail since named capture groups are not supported with sub() functions.

```
regexpr and gregexpr support ‘named capture’. If groups are named,
e.g., "(?<first>[A-Z][a-z]+)" then the positions of the matches are also
returned by name. (Named backreferences are not supported by sub.)
```