# Using more than nine back references in an R regex

Tags: regex, r, gsub, backreference

The code below does not work, because the replacement string for \10, \11, and so on,     cannot be read properly. It reads \10 as \1 and print 0 instead, can you help me fix it?
There is an answer in one of the threads, saying that I am supposed to use capturing or    naming groups, but I don't really understand how to use them.

```
headline <- gsub("regexp with 10 () brackets",
"\\1 ### \\2 ### \\3 ### \\4 ### \\5 ### \\6 ### \\7 ### \\8 ### \\9 ###
\\10### \\11### \\12### \\13### \\14### \\15### \\16",
page[headline.index])
```

Comment: This question looks exactly same as this one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400937/more-than-9-backreferences-in-gsub

Comment: @NarendraYadala -- However, the accepted answer to that question is more or less incorrect. R did not at that time support named groups at all, and even now they are not supported for use by `gsub()`.

Answer (score 3):

According to `?regexp`, named capture has been available in `regexpr()` and `gregexpr()` since R-2.14.0. Unfortunately, it is **not** yet available for `sub()` or, it turns out, `gsub()`. So, it may still be useful to you, but will probably require a bit more legwork than you might have hoped.

(For a few examples of naming groups in action, see the examples section of `?regexpr`.)

**ADDED LATER, FOLLOWING GREG SNOW'S ANSWER**

Greg Snow alluded to the possibility of doing this with the `gsubfn` package.  Here's an example that shows that `gsubfn()` can indeed handle more than nine backreferences:

```
require(gsubfn)
string <- "1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:11"
pat <- "^(\\d)+:(\\d)+:(\\d)+:(\\d)+:(\\d)+:(\\d)+:(\\d)+:(\\d)+:(\\d)+:(\\d)+:(\\d)+"
gsubfn(pat, ~ paste(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,j,i,h,g,f,e,d,c,e,a), string)  
# [1] "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 5 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using `gsubfn` from the `gsubfn` package instead of `gsub`, it gives more options on how to create your replacement.

Comment: +1 -- Thanks for the pointer. I've added an example of its use to my answer, showing that it can indeed handle more than 9 backreferences.