R: how to replace string with digit after capturing group
I need to transform strings like 333bis into 33300, so I set up a regex pattern like (\d{3})(bis), but I can't use \100 as substitute pattern, because it will be interpreted as "group 100". The correct way to do it in python would be \g<1>00, but I would like to know if there is an equivalent for an R function like gsub.

What engine are you using? TRE or PCRE? Do you add perl=TRUE to your gsub?

Actually, gsub("(\\d{3})bis", "\\100", x) works fine - see https://ideone.com/0pWt5t. So the issue is only with the PCRE version, and the solution is known: just use unambiguous ${n} syntax.

Also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400937/more-than-9-backreferences-in-gsub
